# LANSA - unable to use views and joins

Tags: lansa

I'm working against a `DB2` database with a `DotNet` application. Some parts of the system are build and maintained in `AS400 LANSA`, other parts are `DotNet`.

We curently have the issue that we are maintaining a lot of summary table that need to be updated with values of many different tables. This causes our data to be out of sync with each other all the time and we need to run script each night checking and correcting errors.

These tables are required since they claim it is impossible to make join or use views in `LANSA`

Is this correct? Are they alternatives i can supply for them to avoid these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `LANSA` with `RDMLX`, then you can use `SELECT_SQL` to incorporate `JOIN`'s as needed.

By Views, do you mean logical files? Those get used as needed by the database engine automatically. If you mean a `VIEW` created off multiple physical files, then these can be replicated in `LANSA` using pre-determined Join Fields. Have a look at the `LANSA` documentation about these.

You could use something like this:

```
#MYSQLST := ('SELECT {write your SQL select statement here}') Select_Sql Fields({my fields}) Using(#MYSQLST)
```

Worth reviewing the `LANSA` documentation on the use of Free Format `SELECT_SQL`

Comment: If you need to ask the OP a question, it's better to do it in the comments on the question, rather than in *an answer*.